# Postgres Exception handling in stored procedure to continue the process

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Database is postgressql.

I want to call five stored procedure in on stored procedure that is master_call_all() and need to handle exception after every call. So if any error occur it raise the exception and not terminate the process.
Let say error occur in 3rd call scratch.sp_insert3() then after raising error next stored procedure will call. This thing I want to achieve after every call.

```
create or replace procedure scratch.master_call_all()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    call scratch.sp_insert1();
    call scratch.sp_insert2();
    call scratch.sp_insert3();
    call scratch.sp_insert4();
    call scratch.sp_insert5();
commit; 
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: In general this is an **extremely bad plan**. It is the anti-thesis of creating a Transaction (begin ... end).

> *Transactions are a fundamental concept of all database systems*. The essential point of a transaction is that it bundles multiple steps
> into a single, all-or-nothing operation. The intermediate states
> between the steps are not visible to other concurrent transactions,
> and if some failure occurs that prevents the transaction from
> completing, then none of the steps affect the database at all.

Ref: [Database Transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html)

Now with that out of the way, what you are asking can be done, but it is not done cleanly. A code block in Postgres contains 3 sections declaration, execution, exception with declaration and exception optional. Further a block can be nested inside another and the nested block retains all 3 sections. So what you need is to place each ca;; statement into a nested block. Like:

```
create or replace procedure master_call_all()
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
begin
    begin 
        call  sp_insert1();
    exception 
        when others then 
             raise notice 'Exception occurred calling sp_insert1()';
    end ; 
        
        begin 
            call  sp_insert2();
        exception 
            when others then 
                 raise notice 'Exception occurred calling sp_insert2()';
        end ;
     
        begin 
            call  sp_insert3();
        exception 
            when others then 
                 raise notice 'Exception occurred calling sp_insert3()';
        end ;
     
        begin 
            call  sp_insert4();
        exception 
            when others then 
                 raise notice 'Exception occured calling sp_insert4()';
        end ; 
        
        begin 
            call  sp_insert5();
        exception 
            when others then 
                 raise notice 'Exception occured calling sp_insert5()';
        end ;
    
    commit; 
    end;
    $$;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c3c03301b61aaaa092e6b9c334a3d6d5). Unfortunately *db<>fiddle* does not show the messages from `raise notice ...`. Clearly in the demo `sp_insert1`, and `sp_insert3` will raise an exception. (To see the messages run in your environment.)

Comment: Its raising notice everytime but what i want to raise notice only when any call failed and it also not inserting the data into database which I want. All these call are independent so failure one wont affect the other.
I want to achieve to schedule master stored procedure call so that it able to handle exception and call every sp. i know how to schedule but in handling exception I am facing problem

Comment: If the calls are within a single block *begin I; I; I; commit;* (where each I represents an insert statement)  they **are not independent** they form a **single transaction**. Starting at `begin` and ending with `commit` This is true even when individual statements exist in nested blocks.   The only they becomes independent is to commit after each statement. See [Transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-transactions.html).